# Unread inbox messages

Tags: discussion, notifications

I wanted to ask a question about the visual cue that appears when you have a pending message...

[image]

It lights up red and displays the number of pending messages. In this case it is "1".  But sometimes it is a larger value like "7".

The indicator turns itself off as soon as you inspect it, even if there are additional unread messages.  This invites the possibility that you may not visit each of the messages unless you keep track beforehand.

How are people refreshing this indicator so that a user can be sure they have nothing pending?  Alternatively, would this constitute a 'feature request'?

Comment: To overcome this, I usually open the drop down notification list, and then open all notifications un new tabs..

Comment: If someone is reading this, I got a message "Please put ...review" something and then my mouse skipped and aah, the message vanished. Could not see anything more in my account under responses. Was the message deleted or what exactly happened ?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for answering. I looked again, but no message in my responses, so I suppose it really was deleted or modified. The only thing I could glimpse was that it was sth with "review". <shrug>

Answer (score 2):

For want of an answer, two suggestions made in Comments:

> To overcome this, I usually open the drop down notification list, and then open all notifications in new tabs.. – Nean Der Thal Jul 28 '15 at 19:52

.

> The 'unread' notifications are shaded. I start at the bottom of the shaded ones and work upwards